# How to scroll a recyclerView automatically/periodically using a Runnable and boolean flags

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, timertask

I'm faced with a rather challenging situation where I need to scroll a `RecyclerView` automatically and periodically based on flags provided by touch events in my `RecyclerView`.

I have a `RecyclerView` of foldable items and the foldable items have an `ImageView` inside a `ScrollView`.This is a poor implementation I know as a `ScrollView` wont scroll vertically if the parent also does the same.

But since I wanted this feature,I thought of disabling scrolling in my `RecyclerView` when the `ScrollView` is visible so as to have it scroll. I made a custom `LayoutManager` for that as follows:

```
public class ConditionalScrollManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    public ConditionalScrollManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    ConditionalScrollManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return Adapter_Admin.canScroll && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```

However, this brought about an issue where items to the bottom of the screen can't be completely seen as the list is not scrollable after an item is clicked.

The flag `Adapter_Admin.canScroll` comes from my adapter here:

```
canScroll = true;
        flAdmin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            image = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsImage();
            message = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsMessage();

            scrollOne = true;
            scrollTo = getLayoutPosition();

            if (flAdmin.isFolded()) {
                flAdmin.unfoldWithAnimation();
                canScroll = false;
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        canScroll = true;
                    }
                }, 0, 10);

            } else {
                flAdmin.foldWithAnimation();
                canScroll = true;
                scrollOne = false;
            }
        });
```

where the `boolean` *canScroll* is a static global variable. I tried adding the `TimerTask` to make the `RecyclerView` scrollable for like 10 ms so the scrolling can happen here :

```
rvAdmin.addOnItemTouchListener(new TchListener(this, rvAdmin, new TchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            if (Adapter_Admin.canScroll)
                rvAdmin.scrollToPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

then revert the flag back to `false` but it's just not working and I don't get the desired effect.

The *TchListener* is a custom listener to handle touch events.

```
public class TchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private ClickListener clicklistener;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public TchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final ClickListener clicklistener) {

    this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            clicklistener.onLongClick(child, recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clicklistener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}}
```

Comment: Does your recycler get items added perotically? Is that why you need to auto scroll with user interaction?

Comment: If only the last item is the problem, how about calling smoothScrollToPosition() or scrollToPosition() when the last item is clicked? I think in this way, user can unfold the last item and see the last item’s image and unfold it when done.

Comment: Welll yes since the data comes from Firebase but what I want is that when a user clicks an item,the list will scroll to make that item fully visible to ensure its visible but after that make the list unscrollable so the user will be able to scroll the long image.

Comment: @HyunIKim I want this for all items,I said last item as an example

Comment: Then why not call scrollToPosition() everytime user unfolds an item? It will make that item fully visible and make it unscrollable so user will have focused experience to that item.

Comment: @HyunIKim on it.Let me try and tell you what happens

Comment: @HyunIKim,its not working somehow

Comment: Anyone found anything yet?trying all I know but nothings working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After racking my head for a day,I figured out how to do it.
For anyone who might be in such a situation,

Well first of all I used a `LocalBroadCastManager` ,`Handler` and a couple of flags in my `EventListener` to achieve it.Oh what did the trick was `scrollToPositionWithOffset`.

Some code,

```
private BroadcastReceiver scrollReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int scrollTo = intent.getIntExtra(ConstHelper.SCROLL_TO, 0);
        boolean scroll = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConstHelper.SMOOTH_SCROLL, false);

        if (scroll) {
            ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(rvAdmin
                    .getLayoutManager()))
                    .scrollToPositionWithOffset(scrollTo, 8);
        }
    }
};
```

This here was all I needed to do.Send the flag to scroll and amount to scroll by and the `BroadCastManager` did it for me.

I just had to increase the `RecyclerView` `paddingBottom` to make it scroll the last item too.

Oh the `Handler` was to set the flag back to false to disable scrolling after a few seconds;

My `ClickListener` :

```
flAdmin.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            scrollTo = getLayoutPosition();

            image = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsImage();
            message = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsMessage();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ConstHelper.START_SCROLL);
            intent.putExtra(ConstHelper.SMOOTH_SCROLL, true);
            intent.putExtra(ConstHelper.SCROLL_TO, getLayoutPosition());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(itemView.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            if (flAdmin.isFolded()) {
                flAdmin.unfoldWithAnimation();
            } else {
                flAdmin.foldWithAnimation();
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> canScroll = false, 2000);

        });
```

cheers :)